# add twitter widget in wicket onload page

Tags: javascript, wicket, twitter4j

I am new in wicket .
I am trying to add twitter search widget in my wicket page, and want to make it work when 
the page loads. 
https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search

I created a new panel and implement IHeaderContributor

```
public class TwitterPanel extends Panel implements IHeaderContributor{
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)
{
// response.renderOnLoadJavaScript("alert('page loaded!');");


response.renderJavaScriptReference
 ("http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js");
response.renderOnLoadJavaScript
`enter code here`("new TWTR.Widget({"
+"version: 2,".....)

 }}
```

and add this panel in my main page.

I want to make it work when my main page loads.
but it is not happening.
I feel like script is not called.
please help if you have any idea ...to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Check https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/core-1.5.x/jdk-1.5-parent/twitter-parent